# Refreshing jTable does not return updated data

Tags: java

My jTable is not updating my data after insert or update button. My jFrame has 2 functions for refreshing my tables.My first function is running well  but my second is not

Here is my first function that works fine

```
 public void  executeSQLQuery (String query,String message) {
        Connection con =getConnection();
        Statement stt;
        try{
            stt =con.createStatement();
            if((stt.executeUpdate(query))==1)
            {
                //refresh jtable data
                DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable_Products.getModel();
                model.setRowCount(0);
                show_Products_in_Jtable();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data "+message+" Succefully");
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Not "+message+ "Error");
            }

                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
}

public void show_Products_in_Jtable(){
     ArrayList<Update_del_insert_products> list= getproList();
     DefaultTableModel model =(DefaultTableModel)jTable_Products.getModel();
     Object[] row =new Object[7];
     for(int i =0;i< list.size();i++)
     {   
         row[0] = list.get(i).getpro_Id();
         row[1] = list.get(i).getpro_Name();
         row[2] = list.get(i).getpro_Price();
         row[3] = list.get(i).getpro_Quantity();
         row[4] = list.get(i).getpro_Supplier_id();
         row[5] = list.get(i).getpro_Tax();
         row[6] = list.get(i).getcat_productss();       
         model.addRow(row);

     }

 }
```

Here is my query

```
private void AddProductActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String query="INSERT INTO Products(Pro_Id ,Pro_Name,Pro_Price,Pro_Quantity,Pro_Supplier_id,Pro_Tax,Cat_products)VALUES ('"+Pro_Id.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Name.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Price.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Quantity.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Supplier_id.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Tax.getText()+" ','"+Cat_productss.getText()+" ') ";


          executeSQLQuery(query,"Inserted");
}
```

And here is my second function that does not refresh any data.Any idea what i am doing wrong ?

```
           public void  SQLQuery (String qquery,String message) {
            Connection con =getConnection();
            Statement sptt;
            try{
                sptt =con.createStatement();
                if((sptt.executeUpdate(qquery))==1)
                {
                    //refresh jtable data
                    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable_Cat.getModel();
                    model.setRowCount(0);
                    show_cat_in_Jtable();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data "+message+" Succefully");
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Not "+message+ "Error");
                }

                    }catch (Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }

   public void show_cat_in_Jtable(){
         ArrayList<Insert_categories> list= getcatList();
         DefaultTableModel model =(DefaultTableModel)jTable_Cat.getModel();
         Object[] row =new Object[2];
         for(int i =0;i< list.size();i++)
         {   
             row[0] = list.get(i).getcat_id();
             row[1] = list.get(i).getcat_products();
             model.addRow(row);

         }

     }
```

Here is my query

```
 private void Add_CatActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        String qquery="INSERT INTO Categories(Cat_products)VALUES ('"+Cat_products.getText()+" ') ";
        executeSQLQuery(qquery,"Inserted");
    }
```

Comment: Show `show_Products_in_Jtable()` and `show_cat_in_Jtable()` methods code.

Comment: Please post an [mcve] that clearly demonstrates the problem

Comment: When you update the table model, the table does not redraw (or repaint) itself, unless you call one of the fireXXX methods on the model. For example, after addding/updating rows to the model, include a call to `model.fireTableDataChanged()`.

Comment: its not the same table that i want to refresh i have two  saperated tables under the same jframe. So this fire function where is Should call it in my code ? Cause i am really new to all of this ty !

Comment: Any time, any where, you make a change to a Table Model, you need to call the fire method on that Model so the UI gets updated. I recommend you add this line in both of your methods, right after the for loop.

Comment: i add this method but nothing change in refresh . I think iam getting this error cause of the function  execute ?  not ably 2 call both of them  idont know ....